# Drupal — Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found

Tags: php, drupal, memcached

I have installed drupal on my localhost. It worked well 2 months ago, but now something happened and I don't know why. I'll be very grateful if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

The full error looks like this:

> Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not
>   found in
>   /srv/www/htdocs/modules/memcache/dmemcache.inc
>   on line 177

1) php -m gives this:

> [PHP Modules]
>   bz2
>   ctype
>   date
>   dom
>   filter
>   gd
>   hash
>   iconv
>   json
>   libxml
>   mbstring
>   mcrypt
>   mysql
>   mysqli
>   pcre
>   PDO
>   pdo_mysql
>   pdo_sqlite
>   Reflection session SimpleXML SPL
>   SQLite standard sysvsem tokenizer xml
>   xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib
>
> [Zend Modules]
>   none

2) memcached is installed through package manager.

3) memcache module for drupal installed

what am I doing wrong? thx.

Comment: `memcached` or `memcache` should appear in the list of installed modules.  Try running `apt install php8.1-memcached` to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers -- I've eventually managed with this problem.
Here's the solution as for openSUSE 11.1.

1. Install **memcache extension for php**:

   ```
   #if apt-get, rpm, or yum doesn't work
   cd /usr/src/
   wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.5.tgz
   tar -zxvf memcache-2.2.5.tgz
   cd memcache-2.2.5
   phpize5
   ./configure --enable-memcache
   make
   make install
   cp modules/memcache.so /usr/lib/php5/extensions/

   # Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
   # found in the directory /etc/php5/conf.d/
   touch /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini
   echo 'extension=memcache.so' > /etc/php5/conf.d/memcache.ini
   ```

   now you should restart apache2 service
2. Install **memcached daemon for php** and run it as a daemon.
3. Install **memcache plugin for drupal** (all instructions here: http://drupal.org/project/memcache)

**UPD**. be carefull with upgrading PHP: intalled modules might not be working well with new version -- you should recompile them. but somehow "pear install -f pecl/memcache" did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 4):

I convene with googletorp that the problem seems to rely on memcache installation. Try this:

```
#if apt-get, rpm, or yum doesn't work
cd /usr/src/
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.4.tgz
tar -zxvf memcached-2.2.4.tgz
cd memcached-2.2.4
phpize && ./configure --enable-memcache && make
cp modules/memcache.so /usr/lib/php/modules/

# Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
# found in the directory /etc/php.d
touch /etc/php.d/memcached.ini
echo 'extension=memcache.so' > /etc/php.d/memcached.ini

service httpd restart
```

The above procedure has been brutally copied from the comments to the page of the [official memecache documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.installation.php). It is dated 11.12.09.

Comment: Should there be any amendments to the code provided that I work on openSUSE 11.1?
Thx.

Comment: I do not know as I do not run openSUSE on any of my servers. However the only thing that seems like important to be checked is that your php is effectively installed in `/usr/lib/php`. All the rest looks boilerplate to me.

Answer (score 3):

A co-worker helped me today with this issue, I use Drupal & Drush (command line tool), and sometimes MAMP.

Try:

```
echo $PHPRC
```

If it comes up blank then save this in your *~/.profile* or your *~/.bash_profile* config file:

```
export PHPRC='/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini'
```

Comment: It works with MAMP PRO. If you use specific php version, you need to target the right `.ini` file like `export PHPRC='/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.4.2.ini'` To edit the file, you can do `nano ~/.bash_profile`or `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

It seems your memcache drupal module is expecting a class to be available in the inc file mentioned.

- Did you upgrade your drupal module?
- In such cases it's good to look at the issue que for the module on drupal.org.

It looks like it's the drupal module that's the problem. My guess an upgrade went wrong.

**EDIT:**
I Took at look at the module, I was on my iphone, so couldn't look through the code. Your problem is that Drupal can't find the Memcache class. This fix is defined in step two of the installation process.

> 2. Install the PECL memcache extension for PHP. This must be version 2.2.1 or 
>      higher or you will experience errors.

Either you are missing this now, or something is wrong with the installation. In any regard, Drupal can't find the `Memcache` that is defined in this extension, and that is why you get the fatal error.

Comment: thx, i'll try to update it now, but shouldn't be the problem, because it all worked fine. i'm sure the issue is in configuration of php, memcached and other such stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to just add `extension=memcached.so` to your `php.ini`. The location of this file can be found using `phpinfo();`

Make sure you restart apache afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

my take is that memecache may be installed on your machine, but it's not correctly compiled with PHP
had this issue before with memecache.
check [here](http://www.ducea.com/2007/05/17/php-pecl-memcached-module-installation-problems/) for more details